# Por que no salta el error identificador no válido en esta update?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Al actualizar dos campos de una tabla utilizando una subselect para sacar el valor de una columna que no existe, la actualización se realiza en vez de dar el error identificador no válido.

Ejemplo:

```
Update tablaA
Set 
campoA1 =(select campoA1 from TablaB where idB= xxx) , 
campoA2 =(select campoA2 from TablaB where idB= xxx)
Where
Id = aaa
```

Dónde `campoA1` y `campoA2` son columnas de `tablaA` pero no de `tablaB` 
Yo sabiendo esto esperaba que me saliera el error identificador no válido pero en vez de esto me actualiza.

Comment: ¿Y qué valores te quedarían en `campoA1` y `campoA2` tras que actualiza sin arrojarte error?

Comment: Les pone el mismo valor que tenían antes de la actualización.  He probado a realizar en la subselect la llamada de otro campo, digamos campoA3, que existe en la tablaA pero no en la tablaB. El resultado es que los campo, campoA1 y campoA2, se actualizan con el valor campoA3. Soy autodidacta en este tema y más que nada creo que no entiendo el flujo de ejecución de la update. La conclusión que sacó es que, primero se lee la tablaA y luego se hace la select y finalmente actualiza. ??
Gracias.

Comment: La verdad, no sé muy bien si la sintaxis SQL de Oracle diverge mucho de la de MSSQL o Mysql, que son los motores de BD que conozco, pero en ellos, cuando quieres hacer un `update` de datos cruzados entre 2 o más tablas, usas `join` y alias. Tal parece que lo tuyo es más un ejercicio que un desarrollo, ¿es así?

Comment: Aunque sean una subselects los campos campos1 y campoA2 siempre referencian a tableA. Si la subselect existe, dara el valor de campos1 o campoo2 de tableA. Por tanto es un update al mismo valor, es decir, cambian los valores.